# how a nested for loop can be used to increase values in a single variable and move to next with time

Tags: loops, for-loop, time, nested

I am new in coding , the Code is shown below , currently it sets all M(i)variables as 10 when i run the code. 
I want for each variable it should increase from 0 to 10 (1 2 3 4 5 .) each number change in one second and when 10 is reached then move to next variable M(i).

```matlab
function M = fcn(time)
M  =zeros(84,1);
for i=1:84
 for j = 1:10
     M(i) = j*1;
 end
end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps you:

```
int[] m = new int[84];
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 84; i++)
{
    if (j % 10 == 0)
    {
        j = 0;
    }
    m[i] = j * 1;
    j++;
}
```